# Using es6 shortcuts to reduce number of lines in code snippet

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Is there a more concise, prettier way to write this snippet of code? Learning es6 syntactic sugar and was wondering if i can reduce the number of lines for this snippet

```
const checkLoggedInSuccess = ({
  user,
}: {
  user?: User;
}): AuthenticationActionTypes => {
  if (user === undefined) {
    return {
      type: CHECK_LOGGED_IN_SUCCESS,
      isFetching: false,
    };
  } else {
    return {
      type: CHECK_LOGGED_IN_SUCCESS,
      isFetching: false,
      user: {
        email: user.email,
      },
    };
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how'd'ya fancy this?

```
const checkLoggedInSuccess = ({user}: {user?: User}): AuthenticationActionTypes => (
  !!user
    ? {
      type: CHECK_LOGGED_IN_SUCCESS,
      isFetching: false,
    }
    : {
      type: CHECK_LOGGED_IN_SUCCESS,
      isFetching: false,
      user: {
        email: user.email,
      },
    }
)
```